# Group By array value from text field using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'my_data'

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqjno.png)

and field 'input' as type text. And I stored array value in that field as follow

```
array (
  'msisdn' => '99999999999',
  'keyword' => '',
  'serviceid' => '0011001100',
  'productid' => '111000111',
  **'mode' => '02',**
  'cli' => '0000',
  'txnid' => '000000403401806110710441878004',
  'startdate' => '2018-06-06 14:51:45',
  'enddate' => '2018-06-12 00:00:00',
  'type' => 'subscription',
  'renewalon' => '2018-06-12 00:00:00',
  'lastrenewalon' => '2018-06-11 13:06:52',
  'fee' => 2.44,
  'status' => '0',
  'linkid' => '',
)
```

Now, how can I get the values group by **'mode'** from the array value using mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can chain two [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) functions to first get the substring after `'mode'`, and then get the substring before `,'cli'`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a, "'mode'", -1), ",'cli'", 1) AS group_condition
```

Insert the field text in the place of `a`.
Then you can use `group_condition` in the `GROUP BY` clause.